# Go Back to Previous Item

Tags: c#

I have a Back function, and it is growing.  I also think this is terrible, but I don't seem to get how it can be improved:

```cs
public void GoBack()
{
    NavButtonUsed = true;

    Forward.Insert(0, Back[0]);
    Back.RemoveAt(0);

    if (Back[0].Title.StartsWith(" ") && CurrentItem.Menu != Back[0].Menu)
    {
        switch (Back[0].Menu)
        {
            case Menus.WSOneNote:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[0];
                break;

            case Menus.WSMainMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("MainMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.MainMenu), Menus.WSMainMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSTextMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("TextMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.TextMenu), Menus.WSTextMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSTextBlockMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("TextBlockMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.TextBlockMenu), Menus.WSTextBlockMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSTableMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("TableMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.TableMenu), Menus.WSTableMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSTableCellsMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("TableCellsMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.TableCellsMenu), Menus.WSTableCellsMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSDrawMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("DrawMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.DrawMenu), Menus.WSDrawMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSDrawnItemsMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("DrawnItemsMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.DrawnItemsMenu), Menus.WSDrawnItemsMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSPictureMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("PictureMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.PictureMenu), Menus.WSPictureMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSFileMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("FileMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.File), Menus.WSFileMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSAppBarsMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("AppBarsMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.AppBar), Menus.WSAppBarsMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSCharmsMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("CharmsMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.Charms), Menus.WSCharmsMenu))];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(Back[0])];
    NavButtonUsed = false;
}
```

I have more menus to account for, but I haven't implemented going back to them yet as I do not have them fully implemented.  What is really going on here is I need to programmatically select a menu to open it so I can select a menu item within it.  If I do not open the menu, `ItemList` will not have `CurrentItem`, so the app will crash.

This is CurrentItem:

```cs
private MenuItem _currentItem = new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("OneNote"), typeof(WindowsData.OneNote), Menus.WSOneNote);
public MenuItem CurrentItem
{
    get { return _currentItem; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _currentItem) { return; }
        _currentItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

ItemList, Back, and Forward are just `ObservableCollection`s of MenuItems (they can't be `List`s because they are bound to XAML objects that need to know when they are updated).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `GoBack()` method could be simplified in its current pattern to

```
public void GoBack()
{
    NavButtonUsed = true;

    Forward.Insert(0, Back[0]);
    Back.RemoveAt(0);

    CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(Back[0])];

    NavButtonUsed = false;
}
```

The whole `switch..case` is senseless, because the only thing it is doing is triggering the `OnPropertyChanged()` event twice.

Inside the `switch..case` you are assigning a `MenuItem` to the `CurrentItem` property (triggering an `OnPropertyChanged()` event) and you are breaking out of the `switch`.

Then you are assigning `ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(Back[0])]` to the `CurrentItem` property (triggering an `OnPropertyChanged()` event), so you are just overwriting the property.

So, if this method works like intended, the `switch..case` can be removed.

Comment: This won't work because the menu is closed and `CurrentItem` is not in `ItemList`.  If I call `CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(Back[0])];` without opening the menu first, the app will crash. I specified this in my question.

Comment: What type is `Back` ? I assume a `List<MenuItem>`.

Comment: Well, it is an `ObservableCollection` because it is bound to the Back button's visibility.

Comment: ObservableCollection of MenuItem ?

Comment: Yes.  Maybe I should add the all the calls to `Back` into the question?

Comment: I don't know. You can ask in chat if it would be ok to update with more context.

Comment: What is really happening is I use the `switch` statement to open the menu if the menu is not already open.  I'm not sure if there is anything I can do about this, but I wish I could shorten it.  Of course, I could create a list of menus in a different file and scan it for the right menu item with a `foreach` loop, but I have been told by some people to not do that kind of stuff.  What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

instead of

> ```
> get { return _currentItem; }
> set
> {
>     if (value == _currentItem) { return; }
>     _currentItem = value;
>     OnPropertyChanged();
> }
> ```

Where you are checking whether the `_currentItem` is equivalent to the value that you are trying to set it to, you should do the opposite and make it less cluttered.

```
set
{
    if (!(value == _currentItem))
    {
        _currentItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
 }
```

This is the exact same except it is straightforward, "change the value if it's not the same"

---

I also don't like your `get` statement, I would write it like this

```
get
{
    return _currentItem;
}
```

or if you are going for compact, you could also write the `get` statement like this.

```
get;
```

Some people don't like this though.